Image display issue in MAUI XAML
The issue is image is not display when i have created project MAUI. I  am using .net 8 framework.
I have created by default simple project and also check downgrade the packages and also try to upgrade version but my issue is not resolved.

Could you please show the relative code about displaying image? In addition, what platform did you test on?

This question needs more details

I have simple stand alone.net Maui XAML project. I have used window platform

Please confirm whether the image file is placed in Resources -> Images folder and the Build Action is set to MauiImage? In addition, how do you use the image in your code?

Yes image file in resource file.

can you add the relevant code about displaying the image? In the default project you created, in the MainPage, <Image Source="donet_bot.png"...> can display the image normally?

donet_bot.png image is not displayed in main page. Image build action is MauiImage

I have resolved this issue
I have updated Visual Studio Professional 2022 and i have used vs version 17.10.3 and i have also updated three libraries. CommunityToolkit.Maui(9.0.1), Microsoft.Maui.Controls(8.0.60) and Microsoft.Maui.Control.Compatibility(8.0.60).
##My previous visual studio version is 17.10.1 and CommunityToolkit.Maui(8.0.1), Microsoft.Maui.Controls(8.0.40) and Microsoft.Maui.Control.Compatibility(8.0.40).##
After updated my libraries and vs version issue is resolved automatically.

For the issue that the image cannot be displayed in the MAUI Windows project, you need to confirm the following steps:
1.Image file is placed in the Resources->Images folder.

In the .csproj file, confirm that the image path is in the , taking the dotnet_bot.svg as the example:


<ItemGroup>
    <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.svg"/>
</ItemGroup/>



Make sure the name is correct when using image in your project's Pages:


<Image Source="dotnet_bot.png"/>


For more settings about image in MAUI, you can refer to MAUI Image.

Thanks for reply. I have checked all above thing. May be problem in .net framework i have also all Maui libraries upgrade and degrade but problem is not resolved.

Can't the dotnet_bot.png image in the default project normally on different platforms (iOS, Andorid, Windows)， different device versions (iOS17.2/17.4/Android13.0...), different .Net versions (.net7/.net8), and different vs versions (vs community, vs preview)?

I have also used another image but problem is not resolved.

Have you tried re-installing the VS?
